# R - Heteroskedastic robust errors with `bife` package

Tags: econometrics, heteroscedasticity, fixed-effects-model

I'm using a fairly new R package called [`bife`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bife/vignettes/bife_introduction.html) for binary choice fixed effects model.

It looks like `vcovHC` in the `sandwich` package currently doesn't support bife model objects. Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: Not a workaround, but you could try and contact @Achim Zeileis, who maintains the sandwich package and is also active on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a R package called [alpaca](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alpaca/alpaca.pdf) from the same group behind bife that has this functionality. You specify that you want the "sandwiched" errors when running summary on your fitted model.

```
mod <- feglm(Y ~ X | Z | Z, data)
summary(mod, "sandwich")
```

Also neat that it supports multiway fixed-effects!

Comment: Alpaca seems to be catered more to large and long panels though, while bife can handle short panels. That might be an issue for some studies.